# Show a popupwindow to right of finger on longClick

Tags: android, popupwindow, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to show a popupwindow onlongclick and it has to be positioned to the right of your finger.

I was reading the android documentation for popupwindow here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html but the 'show' methods seems to all require anchors and parents for the view that the popupwindow must be anchored to before it can be shown.

When I onLongClick the screen at any random location, there is  not necessarily going to be a view under my finger that I can use to pass in as an anchor for the popupwindow to show underneath my finger.

Currently I'm using the following code to show my popupwindow:

```
            photoOptionsPUWindow.showAtLocation(coordinatorLayout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, x+50, y+50);
```

The +50 is to show the popupwindow slightly to the right of where I pressed.

However, because I have anchored it to my coordinatorlayout which is match_parent for width and height, the popupwindow rest to the right of the top of my screen which is not what I want.

[image]

How can I achieve the effect of showing my popupwindow slightly to the right of my finger? Facebook managed to achieve it with their app so it definitely can be done.